# add values that are the same within a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector 
`x <- c(1,2,5,4,3,1,1,4,2,6,7,2,4,1,5)`
and I want to add the values that are the same, giving me the new vector
`x <- c(4, 6, 3, 12, 10, 6, 7)`
It sounds quite simple but I am stuck.

Comment: So to be clear, you want a new vector containing the sums of unique elements, in the sequence fo the first occurence of each element? Or how else is your outcome ordered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to iterate over the vector of the `unique` values, and then sum each one of the corresponding entries, like so:

```r
> sapply(unique(x), function(i) sum(x[x == i]))
[1]  4  6 10 12  3  6  7
```

If the order is relevant, please indicate which order do you want.

In this solution, the order is the same as the output of `unique`, which you can use to know what is the sum of what value.

```r
> unique(x)
[1] 1 2 5 4 3 6 7
```

### Edit

It looks like you want the ascending order of unique values. In that case, you can do like this:

```r
> sapply(sort(unique(x)), function(i) sum(x[x == i]))
[1]  4  6  3 12 10  6  7
```

Comment: Nice one. So if you do `sapply(sort(unique(x))....)` you get the output given by OP.

Comment: ^^ was about to say that

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out after looking at his output again

Answer (score 2):

```
aggregate(x, list(number = x), FUN = sum )
#  number  x
#1      1  4
#2      2  6
#3      3  3
#4      4 12
#5      5 10
#6      6  6
#7      7  7
```

The result is a data.frame and you can extract the second column as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, for fun:

```
with(rle(sort(x)), lengths * values)
# [1]  4  6  3 12 10  6  7
```

**Benchmarks**

```
library(microbenchmark)
x <- c(1,2,5,4,3,1,1,4,2,6,7,2,4,1,5)
x <- rep(x, length.out=1000)

matthew <- function() with(rle(sort(x)), lengths * values) 
iled <- function() sapply(sort(unique(x)), function(i) sum(x[x == i])) 
kota <- function() as.numeric(table(x) * as.integer(names(table(x))))
deena <- function() {
    freqTable = as.data.frame(table(x))
    as.numeric(as.character(freqTable$x)) * freqTable$Freq
}
roland <- function() aggregate(x, list(number = x), FUN = sum )$x


microbenchmark(matthew(), iled(), kota(), deena(), roland())

# Unit: microseconds
#       expr    min     lq   mean median     uq  max neval
#  matthew()  105.5  116.9  167.5  122.5  131.3 1466   100
#     iled()  111.2  125.6  160.3  131.4  138.8 1449   100
#     kota() 1821.5 1899.3 1960.4 1915.9 1940.7 3031   100
#    deena() 1124.7 1175.6 1221.1 1187.9 1207.7 2700   100
#   roland() 1912.2 1967.9 2116.6 1995.5 2078.5 3610   100
```

Comment: ahaha thank you for this, it actually is interesting, useful -- and fun!

Comment: It's close. If you take out the `sort`, your's is fastest. My answer, however, requires the sort.

Comment: Awesome! This is actually very useful! Also the order of the elements of the resulting vector is irrelevant. Well Done @iled !

Comment: If there had been any indication that performance is important, I'd have expected an indication of the size of the input vector and the number of unique values. In such a case, I would probably have used data.table. However, clarity of code seemed more important ...

Comment: Yes, because for this case the input vector is always going to be small ( < 15 elements). However, it is good to know about performance for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be multiplying each element with its frequency. The `table` function does a good with that :

```
freqTable = as.data.frame(table(x))
requiredResult = as.numeric(as.character(freqTable$x)) * freqTable$Freq
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute `#n * n` for each `n`, where `#n` is the number of occurrence of `n`.

Just an alternative approach to the `sapply` above.

```
table(x) * as.integer(names(table(x)))
# x
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
#  4  6  3 12 10  6  7
```